# Sequence on MSP430 C code skipping certain flags

Tags: microcontroller, adc, c, embedded

I am developing some code for the [MSP-EXP430FR5994](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau367p/slau367p.pdf?ts=1649150529600&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR5969), specifically code using the MSP430's ADC. My plan for the ADC is to run a dual-channel ADC capture. However, I have only been able to run the code within the first channel.

Here is my relevant ADC code.

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;               // Stop WDT

    // GPIO Setup
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                         // Clear LED to start
    P1DIR |= BIT0 | BIT1 | BIT2 ;
    P1SEL1 |= BIT3 | BIT4 ;
    P1SEL0 |= BIT3 | BIT4 ;                 // 1.2 set to TA1.1, 1.3 and 1.4 set to ADC input (A3)
    P1SEL0 |= BIT2 ;                        // Check p88-90_s for what the hell we're doing in the last 3 lines

    PJSEL0 = BIT4 | BIT5;                   // For XT1? (p118_s)

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
    P1OUT |= BIT0;

    // Clock System Setup
    CSCTL0_H = CSKEY_H;                     // Unlock CS registers
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_3;                     // Set DCO to 4MHz (p105)
    CSCTL2 = SELA__VLOCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;   // Set clock source
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__1 | DIVS__4 | DIVM__1;   // Set all dividers, clock speed 1MHz
    CSCTL4 &= ~LFXTOFF;                     // Something related to the 32kHz oscillator, idfk

    do
    {
        CSCTL5 &= ~LFXTOFFG;                // Clear XT1 fault flag
        SFRIFG1 &= ~OFIFG;
    } while (SFRIFG1 & OFIFG);              // Test oscillator fault flag

    CSCTL0_H = 0;

    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12SHT0_0 | ADC12MSC | ADC12ON;      // Sampling time, S&H=4, ADC12 on [p893, CTL0 = control 0, SHT0_0 = sample & hold time, knowledge of register value from p88_s]

    ADC12CTL1 = ADC12SHP | ADC12SHS_4 | ADC12CONSEQ_3; // Use TA1.1 to trigger, (SHP means using sample timer (p897), SHS means "sample-and-hold source select" (p895, p84_s)
                                                       // which selects which source is used to activate sampling (4 being TA1.1 because of p84_s), CONSEQ_3 = Conversion sequence select,
                                                       // 3 means repeated-multiple-channel which means multiple channels are converted and sampled, memory gets overriden everytime (p881)
    ADC12CTL2 |= ADC12RES_2;                // 12-bit conversion results, p897
    ADC12CTL3 |= ADC12CSTARTADD_3;          // Use MEM3/MCTL3 as first, p898

    ADC12MCTL3 = ADC12INCH_3;               // A3 ADC input select from Input Channel 3 (p901), output to MEM3
    ADC12MCTL4 = ADC12INCH_4 | ADC12EOS;    // A4 ADC input select, also setting EOS bit at A4

    ADC12IER0 |= ADC12IE3 | ADC12IE4 ;      // Enable ADC interrupt [IER = interrupt enable, for IFG0 bit, which tells us when the sequence is complete]
    ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC;        // Start sampling/conversion

    // Configure TimerA1.1 to periodically trigger the ADC12 (Change later)
    TA1CCR0 = 31250-1;                      // PWM Period for TA1, change to 32Hz, 31250/1000000 = /32
    TA1CCTL1 = OUTMOD_3;                    // TACCR1 set/reset (Shape of set/reset in p652)

    TA1CCR1 = 15625;                          // TACCR1 PWM Duty Cycle
    TA1CTL = TASSEL__SMCLK | MC__UP;        // SMCLK, up mode
    
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits | GIE);     // Enter LPM0, enable interrupts

}

// ADC12 interrupt service routine
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=ADC12_B_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12ISR (void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC12_B_VECTOR))) ADC12ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    switch(__even_in_range(ADC12IV, ADC12IV__ADC12RDYIFG))
    {
//Some other flags that were not in use have been removed from this sample. Please let me know if these flags are needed to replicate my code.
        case ADC12IV__ADC12IFG3:            // Vector 18:  ADC12MEM3
            //P1OUT ^= BIT5;
            printf("Got here 3.\n");
            break;
        case ADC12IV__ADC12IFG4:           // Vector 20:  ADC12MEM4
            //P1OUT ^= BIT5;
            printf("Got here 4.\n");
            ADC12MCTL4 |= ADC12EOS;
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

I placed a printf statement within both Flag 3 and Flag 4 (in case ADC12IV__ADC12IFG3: and case ADC12IV__ADC12IFG4:). I expected a printf from both Flag 3 and Flag 4. However, I only received a printf from Flag 3.

Please let me know if there's anything obvious I have misplaced. Also, please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: What specific trouble are you having with running your code on the other ADC channel.

Comment: The trouble I am reaching is that the code itself doesn't reach the other ADC channel. I've tested it with printf.

Comment: I placed a printf statement within both Flag 3 and Flag 4. I expected a printf from both Flag 3 and Flag 4. However, I only received a printf from Flag 3.
I was under the impression the code included this information, but I'll update the question to include this information, thanks.

Comment: May I assume that the code previously set ADC12MCTL1 and ADC12MCTL2 and you removed these lines because you don't care to read these channels?

Comment: Don't use printf debugging for embedded code. Set breakpoints and examine the contents of registers and variables directly. If you are using an MSP430 then you should be able to debug using Code Composer Studio.

Comment: @BenVoigt The example code I based my current code on previously set ADC12MCTL0 and only MCTL0. There is a bit (ADC12CTL3 |= ADC12CSTARTADD_3) that controls which memory is written onto first. The dual-channel functionality is something I am trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as soon as main() is done executing, your program counter jumps into la-la land and crashes, also known as "runaway code".

Bare metal embedded systems never return from main(). There is nowhere to return to. The most correct form of main() is the implementation-defined form:

```
void main (void);
```

(On gcc compile with `-ffreestanding` to target embedded systems.)

Inside main(), you need to have an eternal loop which never stops:

```
void main (void)
{
   /* misc init code here */

   /* enable all maskable interrupts here */
   for(;;)
   {
     /* kick watchdog here */

     /* run application code here */
   }
}
```